# How to convert <br> to line breaks when downloadgin html as text file?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use following code to download a `DIV` content as a `text file`.

In 'DIV` I have used  br tag for line brek. but when I download the text file the br is showed instead of line break.

How to make line breaks in generated text file?

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
writer.Write(Dvresult.InnerHtml);
writer.Flush();
stream.Position = 0;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename={0}", "Result.txt"));
Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ToArray());
Response.End();
```

This is part of result:

[image]

Comment: Next you'll be asking how to make text between `<b>` tags bold, and before you know it, you're writing your own HTML parser...

Comment: I'm asking about <br/> tag not <B> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
writer.Write(Dvresult.InnerHtml);
```

To:

```
writer.Write(Dvresult.InnerHtml.Replace("<br/>", "\r\n"));
```

Comment: Just make sure you're doing a case-insensitive Replace, so that you'll catch `<BR/>` and `<bR/>` and so on. And also add another Replace clause to replace unterminated elements, like `<br>` because they're acceptable HTML.

Comment: Not to mention `<br />` and `<br    />`.
Did I already mention HTML parsing is hard?

Answer (score 0):

Or perhaps you should just use the correct property in the first place:

```
writer.Write(Dvresult.InnerText);
```

Why are you reading data from a server-side div anyway? This just smells of bad design. If it's data coming from the client, it should be a text box, or a hidden field. If it's data coming from the sever, why would you pass it through a div?